# Is the derivative of T(t) over the magnitude of T(t) always the unit normal vector?

Tags: vectors, physics, orthonormal

If you have an equation $$r(t)=\langle 1,\cos(t),\sin(t)\rangle$$ then $$r'(t)=\langle 0,-\sin(t),\cos(t)\rangle $$ and $$\|r'(t)\|=\sqrt{\sin^2(t)+\cos^2(t)}=1$$
thus $T(t)=\langle 0,-\sin(t),\cos(t)\rangle$.

Intuitively, it makes sense that finding the rate of change of $T(t)$, aka $T'(t)$ should, would always be normal to the $T(t)$. This is simply explained that as the magnitude of  $r'(t)$ never changes, the acceleration must always only be acting to change direction hence being perpendicular.

However, if you have an equation

$$r(t)=\langle t,2t^2,t^2/2\rangle$$
then
$$r'(t)=\langle 1,4t,t\rangle$$
and 
$$\|r'(t)\|=\sqrt{1+17t^2}$$

In this case, the magnitude of $r'(t)$ is changing so why should the rate of change of $T(t)$ be perpendicular to the path of $T(t)$ and $r'(t)$? In physical scenarios, the only circumstances which acceleration is perpendicular to velocity are where the velocity magnitude is unchanging.

Comment: The unit tangent's magnitude is unchanging. It doesn't matter whether the magnitude of $r'(t)$ changes, as long as $T(t)$ has fixed magnitude, its derivative will be perpendicular to $T(t)$.

Comment: @jgon That is a simple answer that makes incredible sense, thank you. To clear up a tiny confusion is that in the case of r’(t) it should be in the same direction of T(t) right? But r’’(t) is not necessarily in the direction of T’(t)?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. $r'(t)$ is in the same direction as $T(t)$, since $T(t)$ is the normalization of $r'(t)$, but $r''(t)$ is not necessarily (or even usually) in the direction of $T'(t)$. This is because unless $r'(t)$ has constant magnitude, $r''(t)$ will usually have a nonzero component in the $T(t)$ direction, corresponding to the change in the length of $r'$.

Comment: To see this, note that $r'(t) = \|r'(t)\|T(t)$, and differentiating gives us $\frac{d\|r'(t)\|}{dt} T(t) + \|r'(t)\| T'(t)$.

Comment: Uniform circular motion is an interesting example, in which the velocity has constant magnitude but changes direction,  so that the acceleration is towards the center.

Comment: Ahh, I see, this is probably what you were referring to.   (Should have read more carefully.)

Comment: Everyone thank you so much for your answers. This makes so much sense now!